# How configure ArcGIS 10 Server for .NET at http://server/rootContext/ArcGIS rather than http://server/ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0

We are developing a Flex application which will communicate with ArcGIS server via a reverse proxy. The reverse proxy configuration is such that the host and path portions are separate configurations. Does anyone know if you can configure ArcGIS to respond to a URL like:

http://serverName/rootContext/ArcGIS

rather than the default:

http://serverName/ArcGIS

Has anyone done this? Any suggestions on how that might be done?

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 2):

How to do this varies by which web server you are using for the reverse proxy and which ArcGIS Server you are using (.NET or Java).

There are several knowledge base articles on the Esri website that describes [how to setup a reverse proxy](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/search-result?searchKeyWord=Configure+a+reverse+proxy+system+architecture+for+ArcGIS+Server&searchButton=search&clearCacheTime=1297494100&searchRC=All&searchCollectionType=0&searchLanguage=).

One critical element of a reverse proxy is to setup the external url. This can be configured at c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ArcGIS\rest\rest.config or C:\ArcGIS\java\web_output\rest\WEB-INF\classes\server.properties.